# spl_autoload not loading (case sensitivity?)

Tags: php, zend-framework2, spl-autoload-register

I'm using ZF2 as a library. I've got a pretty standard implementation of `spl_autoload_register` which looks like the following:

```
set_include_path(join(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    get_include_path(),
    ROOT . DS . 'library',
    ROOT . DS . 'application',
)));

spl_autoload_register();
```

Where:

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

On my Mac, everything is working fine. On my CentOS server, nope. The only time I've seen an issue like this with `spl_autoload_register` not liking something is when I've tried to use CamelCasing etc. Obviously, this isn't the case. I'm trying to load:

```
\Zend\Config\Config
```

Now, my directory structure looks like this:

```
/application
    /controller
    /model
       /objects
       /dao
       /weeeeeeee 
    /view
      /template_html
/library
    /core
    /Zend
      /Config
```

You get the idea.

So, why is this not working?

EDIT: please tell it's not looking for config.php instead of Config.php...

Comment: Whats your callback for `spl_autoload_register()` look like?

Comment: @alex I don't have a callback as such.

Comment: Just checking into it. Any reason for wrapping `__FILE__` with `dirname()` twice? Also, does your PHP support `__DIR__` ?

Comment: I started with this code a few years ago, so I can't give a reason now. I haven't checked to see if m PHP supports `__DIR__` - BUT - it's working fine with my other libraries, just not the Zend stuff.

Comment: You could register a callback, and dump the classname it's passing, as well as the concatenation of your constants, to ensure something isn't screwy.

Comment: I've got a feeling....  `/home/nginx/domains/iscrm/public/library/Zend\Config\Config.php`

Answer (score 2):

`spl_autoload` is case-sensitive. All classes are mapped to lowercase filenames. Yes, this is insane.  Google php bugs #49625 and #48129 for some backstory.

Solutions:

1. Rename all included classes to lowercase, including all containing paths
2. Write a better autoloader that handles mixed case paths
3. Use Composer's autoloader.

Renaming everything is unrealistic and silly and I don't want to re-invent the wheel again, but I'm having good luck loading custom libraries with Composer's autoloader.

[Composer autoload reference](http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading)

Composer has a [ZF2 package](https://packagist.org/packages/zendframework/zendframework), but you could manually load yours by adding an autoload definition to your `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"Zend": "library/"}
    }
}
```